# Is there a feat to make ranged attacks without provoking attacks of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, feats, ranged-attack

In D&D 3.5 or Pathfinder, is there a non-epic feat that allows you to make a ranged attack at an adjacent opponent without provoking an attack of opportunity?

Comment: Also review your area on the map. Remember you can do a 5-foot step that doesn't provoke an attack of opportunity and fire from that space as long as you are no longer in an opponent's threat area.

Answer (score 10):

Pathfinder has [Point Blank Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-master-combat):

> ## Point Blank Master (Combat)
>
> *You are adept at firing ranged weapons in close quarters.*
>
> **Prerequisite**: [Weapon Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-specialization-combat---final) with selected ranged weapon.
>
> **Benefit**: Choose one type of ranged weapon. You do not provoke attacks of opportunity when firing the selected weapon while threatened.
>
> **Normal**: Using a ranged weapon while you are threatened provokes attacks of opportunity.
>
> **Special**: Starting at 6th level, a ranger with the archery combat style may select Point Blank Master as a combat style feat, but he must have [Weapon Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-focus-combat---final) instead of Weapon Specialization in the selected weapon.

These more specific feats are also available for characters who can't meet its requirements:

- [Close-Quarters Thrower](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/close-quarters-thrower-combat) for one kind of *thrown* weapon.
- [Sword and Pistol](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/sword-and-pistol-combat) for characters using a one-handed ranged weapon, including small crossbows, together with a melee weapon. (This feat has the benefit of not being restricted to one type of weapon, also)

Answer (score 8):

For 3.5e, I can't find a feat. There is another way, however:

The *Master Thrower* prestige class (Complete Warrior) has the Defensive Throw ability, which lets you make a concentration check to use thrown weapons without provoking an op.

The *Order of the Bow Initiate* prestige class (Complete Warrior) has Close Combat Shot, which lets you use ranged weapons without provoking an op.

The spell *Arrow Mind* (Complete Adventurer/Spell Compendium) lets you avoid provoking an op with the listed types of bows

Comment: There's the Arrow Mind spell, too. CAdv/SpC, if I recall.

Answer (score 7):

There's [Point Blank Master](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-master-combat) in Pathfinder. It requires Weapon Specialization (which requires Fighter level 4), unless you're a level 6+ Ranger and taking it as a bonus feat at which point you only need Weapon Focus.

I don't see a similar feat in 3.5.

Answer (score 5):

While not a feat, and quite specific, Pathfinder's [Skirmisher archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo---ranger-archetypes/skirmisher) for Rangers has the following trick:

> **Defensive Bow Stance (Ex):** The Ranger can use this trick as a swift action. Until the start of his next turn, his ranged attacks do not provoke attacks of opportunity.

If you don't find it necessary to spend a feat, and don't mind the loss of your few Ranger spells, the trick is a good alternative usable on a times per day basis.

Answer (score 5):

In the *Dragon Magazine* #335 (Sept. 2005) Class Acts column "Favored Enemy Feats," John E. Ling presents the general feat **No Threat to Me** (91) that has the hefty prerequisites of base attack bonus +7, the feat Point Blank Shot (*Player's Handbook* 98), and the special ability favored enemy like that of a ranger. A creature that possesses the feat when the creature makes a ranged attack doesn't provoke attacks of opportunity from one the creature's favored enemy types that's picked when the feat's gained.

In other words, an archer that possesses the feat **No Threat to Me (giants)** wouldn't provoke attacks of opportunity for any ranged attacks she made while in any giant's threatened area.

If willing to go farther afield, the third-party but Wizards of the Coast-licensed [*Warcraft: The Role-playing Game*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588460711) (July 2003) presents the feat **Close Shot** (108) that is available as a fighter bonus feat and that has as its prerequisites a Dexterity score of 13, a base attack bonus of +4, and the feats Point Blank Shot and Precise Shot (*PH* 98). It simply completely eliminates provoking attacks of opportunity for making ranged attacks. However, it should be noted that this feat predates the epic feat Combat Archery (*Complete Warrior* (Dec. 2003) 151). Because of *both* the feat's status as an outlier *and* the far higher prerequisites of the feat Combat Archery, a DM may decline to allow the feat Close Shot into his campaign.

Answer (score 1):

My answer(s) is specific to Pathfinder.

I see that people have answered with several viable options, but often require taking class levels in something. In the case of Point Blank Master you pretty much have to be a fighter due to one of the required pre-req feats.

There is the [snapshot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/snap-shot-combat) feat which came out in Ultimate Combat. While it does require many feats to get they are likely feats you would already take for a ranged weapon.

> #### Snap Shot (Combat)
>
> With a ranged weapon, you can take advantage of any opening in your opponent’s defenses.
>
> **Prerequisite:** Dex 13, Point-Blank Shot, Rapid Shot, Weapon Focus, base attack bonus +6.
>
> **Benefit:** While wielding a ranged weapon with which you have Weapon Focus, you threaten squares within 5 feet of you. You can make attacks of opportunity with that ranged weapon. You do not provoke attacks of opportunity when making a ranged attack as an attack of opportunity.
>
> **Normal:** While wielding a ranged weapon, you threaten no squares and can make no attacks of opportunity with that weapon.

Comment: Please use a proper quote box when quoting large chunks of text. You can create one by starting each paragraph with `>`. The four-spaces that you have been using create a code box, which is our best option for tabular data (and, if it comes up, actual code), but very inappropriate for quotes.

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is through the soulbow (complete psionics)prestige class.

close combat shot: At 4th level, you can attack with your mind arrow while in a threatened square and not provoke attacks of opportunity.